# How to calculate lsmeans from a glm model with family=binomial?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lsmeans

I would like to calculate adjusted means from a glm model with family = binomial.

This is my script:

```
data$Phenotype<- as.factor(data$Phenotype)
data$Batch<- as.factor(data$Batch)
data$Tray<- as.factor(data$Tray)
data$Genotype<- as.factor(data$Genotype)
model = glm((Phenotype)~ Batch + Tray + Genotype, data=data, family = binomial())

leastsquare = lsmeans(model,"Genotype", rg.limit = 200000)
leastsquare = lsmeans(model,~Genotype, rg.limit = 200000)
leastsquare = emmeans(model,"Genotype", rg.limit = 200000)
leastsquare = emmeans(model,~Genotype, rg.limit = 200000)
leastsquare
```

No matter what line, it doesn't calculate the lsmeans... I obtain this:

```
Genotype   lsmean SE df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 LM1_1_1 nonEst NA NA        NA        NA
 LM1_1_2 nonEst NA NA        NA        NA
 LM1_1_3 nonEst NA NA        NA        NA
 LM1_2_1 nonEst NA NA        NA        NA
 LM1_2_2 nonEst NA NA        NA        NA
 LM1_2_3 nonEst NA NA        NA        NA
 LM1_2_4 nonEst NA NA        NA        NA
Results are averaged over the levels of: Tray, Batch 
Results are given on the logit (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Could you help me? Does anyone know how to calculate lsmeans from glm model?

I expect to obtain adjusted means of my phenotype, corrected for localisation effects, thanks to a glm model with binomial distribution.

Thanks,

LM

Answer (score 0):

You have done it the right way, but it appears that none of them are estimable. You might get a hint at why by doing

```
coef(model)
```

I would guess that several of the regression coefficients are `NA`, meaning that those predictors were excluded from the model. And more to the point, I'd guess that the genotypes are rather unevenly distributed among trays and batches, so that by averaging over them, there's bound to be a hole somewhere.

You can only estimate what the model is able to estimate.

By the way, all four of your `leastsquare` calls are exactly equivalent, except for the labelling of the output, so you only have needed to do one of them.

Comment: PS -- I think the only workaround is to omit either `Tray` or `Batch` from the model. I'm not sure what these are, but apparently they are related closely enough to render everything non-estimable. And the fact that you had `rg.limit=200000` suggests that you're dealing with almost 200,000 combinations of those three factors. Something's gotta go...